# Returning a list created by applying function parameter to all elements equal to the value/predicate parameter

Tags: lambda, lisp, common-lisp

Hey I've been searching for a while now with no clear direction. I know it's in the area of funcalls but am having trouble. My 2 questions are below. Also I'm not sure if I sure if I should be separating them into 2 different threads. Help please. Thank you!

```
;;
;;  returns a list created by applying its function parameter to all elements equal to the value parameter. All other elements remain unchanged 
;;

(defun find-and-do (lst val fun)
  "(find-and-do '() 1 (lambda (x) (+ x 1))) → NIL
(find-and-do '(1 2 3) 2 (lambda (x) (* x 2))) → (1 4 3)
(find-and-do '(1 2 3) 2 (lambda (x) (* x 2))) → (1 4 3)
(find-and-do '(1 2 3 4) 2 #'sqrt) → (1 1.4142135623730951 3 4) 
(find-and-do '(a b c) 'b #'list) → (A (B) C) "

;(lambda (x) (funcall fun val ))) ; what I have so far
; I think id instead off val in the call above it would have to simultaneously pull the elements and modify them from a newly copied list
)

;;
;;  same as find-and-do, but instead of matching a value, apply the function parameter to those elements for which the predicate parameter applied results in true. 
;;

(defun test-and-do (lst predp fun)
  "(test-and-do '() #'evenp (lambda (x) (+ x 1))) → NIL
(test-and-do '(1 2 3 4) #'evenp (lambda (x) (* x 2))) → (1 4 3 8)"

; no idea
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I'd write `test-and-do`:

```
(defun test-and-do (lst pred fun)
  (mapcar (lambda (x)
            (if (funcall pred x)
                (funcall fun x)
                x))
          lst))
```

`find-and-do` can be implemented in terms of `test-and-do`:

```
(defun find-and-do (lst val fun)
  (test-and-do lst (lambda (x) (equal val x)) fun))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The syntax makes perfect sense. Great thinking on equating x to just be another predecessor. What topic would this be under? I'm looking under funcall lamba mapcar function arguments but only get to use it straight forward and not pass it through a function. Thanks again!

Comment: It's looking like the topic "higher order functions".

Comment: Predicate, not predecessor. :-)